# How can i cancel an SQL query 'update' in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

please i need help, i want to cancel an SQL query  in postgresql (update) after the execution
 how can i do that ?

this is my sql query:

```
UPDATE mail_activity2 SET activity_type_id =3 WHERE activity_type_id = 5 ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by cancel? Is it still running or you want revert changes? In first scenario just kill the query, in second you need a logic to recover old values or restore from backup.

Comment: this depends on the SQL client you are using. I believe in `psql` you can simply hit `Ctrl-C`

Comment: `after the execution how can i do that ?` - Restore from backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean the condition will always be false? like below

```
UPDATE mail_activity2 SET activity_type_id =3 WHERE 1=2
```

Comment: No, i want to revert change made by this query